# Finding Errant Output to System.out in Large Java Program

Tags: java, console, debugging

We have a large java code base [~1 M Lines].

Buried (somewhere) in the code base is some old debug output to System.out that we want to remove (its cluttering things up).

The problem is:  out code base is so large that we can't easily find where the output is coming from.  What we want is a way to see where System.out.println is getting called from (like a stack trace from an exception or some such).

Its not suitable to debugging -- the errant output is coming from some errant thread somewhere etc.

Any ideas on how to track the source of this errant output down?

PS: 99.99% of calls to System.out are legit, and we have thousands of them, so simply searching the code base for System.out calls is not a solution!

Comment: @SvrGuy: you could replace all the *System.out.println* with proper logging calls then you'll know where they're called from.  You could also replace all the *System.out* calls by appending the class name where they're coming from to the *System.out.println* call.  Both can be done easily by using some scripting language (some scripting skills is mandatory for any programmer but I digress). Been there, done that: I've replaced all System.out.println by proper logging automagically by a Un*x Bash shell script on a 100 KLOC Java codebase.

Comment: @SvrGuy: Using a shell script and combining tools such as, say, *find*, *sed* and *awk* is a bit of a hack, but you're there to control that nothing goes wrong.  Basically I'd use *find* to find every *.java* file and inside each file I'd replace lines starting (ignoring tab/spaced) with *System.out.println(* with *System.out.println(".java_file_name" + "*.  Heck if you're using a cool DVCS you could clone you're ~1M codebase in a split second and find the worst offenders in a fork and then delete the worst offenders in the "real" codebase, making sure you're not messing anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `System.setOut()` method.  If you are really desperate, set this to some wrapper of real stdout and do whatever in your wrapper.  E.g. compare written string against something and throw if that's the errant output.

Comment: I think this is exactly correct. Make your own stream and when the offending message comes through. Just print a stack trace:

new RuntimeException().printStackTrace();

Comment: Great answer!  It doesn't require real desperation - I think it could be completed in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

With AspectJ, you can easily print the signature for the class that calls System.out.

A simple example that will be adviced by the TraceAspect follows below. The important part is that the class is in the demo package and calls System.out. The aspect will also advice all calls to System.out from all classes in a subpackage of any depth of the demo package.

```
package demo;

public class DemoClass {

    public void demo() {
        System.out.println("inside demo method..");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DemoClass().demo();
    }
}
```

To print out the package and class name before the the System.out is called, you can add an Aspect like this:

```
@Aspect
public class TraceAspect {

    @Pointcut("call(* java.io.PrintStream.*(..))")
    public void sysoutPointcut() {
    }

    @Pointcut("within(demo..*)")
    public void packagePointcut() {
    }

    @Before("sysoutPointcut() && packagePointcut()")
public void beforeSysoutCallInsideDemoPackage(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.print(joinPoint.getThis().getClass().getName() + ":"
            + joinPoint.getSourceLocation().getLine() + " - ");
}
}
```

The output of executing the main method in the DemoClass is:

```
demo.DemoClass:6 - inside demo method..
```

With Eclipse and the AspectJ plugin, you can right-click on your project and click Configure --> Convert to AspectJ project. Then the code above will work.

I have written more about AspectJ with @AspectJ style [here](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/20/aspectj-cheat-sheet/).